# How to turn the volume to max programmatically on android?

Tags: android, volume, android-music-player

I am writing an app for android that turns up the volume and plays a song for 45 seconds and then stops.  That works great, however I can only get the volume to turn up to 50%, Is there a way to turn the volume up to 100% using setVolume()?

This is my code:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);

//plays eye of the tiger for 45 seconds
if (messages.contains("MUSIC ONLY")){

    //turn up the volume
    mp.setVolume(20, 20);
    mp.start();

    //play ring tone for 45 seconds
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mp.stop();
        }
    }, 45000);
}
```

Comment: That seems terribly obnoxious.  I can see why the API might limit you to 50% volume.

Comment: In any case: http://sagistech.blogspot.com/2010/07/setting-android-volume-programmatically.html, and the duplicate linked in your question, above.  Basically, you want to be using the AudioManager class, not the MediaPlayer class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - if this 50% limiting is indeed true, my guess would be that's because of hearing protection. That's what happens when setting volume up in stock Android - it let's you to go to 50%, then asks if you are sure you want to go higher as it may damage your hearing. **Edit:** [from the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html): `This API is recommended for balancing the output of audio streams within an application.` - so if system volume is at 50%, `MediaPlayer.setVolume()` won't go above it.

Comment: I'm just writing a "find my phone" app for class,  it does need to go louder because 50% is barely audible.  But thank you everyone for suggesting the AudioManager class.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the following snippet, using [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html):

```
AudioManager am = 
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamVolume(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
    0);
```

This sets the volume to the maximum level (`getStreamMaxVolume()`) for the `STREAM_MUSIC` (which is on example a song played). For other types of sounds, use different value, like `STREAM_RING` etc.

Comment: I have tried to use AudioManager before but for some reason eclipse doesn't like getSystemService(String)  -->  it is underlined in red and asks me to create a method by that name.  I have imported AudioManager but I am not sure how to rectify this issue otherwise.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Sarah - it is `Context.getSystemService()` actually. So you need to have a `Context` object (like an `Activity` or `Service` for instance. From which class are you calling it?

Comment: How can I set the volume to the middle?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia - have you tried `am.setStreamVolume(..., am.getStreamMaxVolume(...) / 2, ...);` - so, in other words, divide the max volume by two? `.getStreamMaxVolume()` returns an `int`, so it should work just fine.