# how to turn off wifi,bluetooth,data,gps,and reduce disable brightness-voloms in android?

Tags: android, service, wifi

i need to turn off all services in android (wifi,bluetooth,data,gps,and reduce display brightness-voloms) XD.
i just google it and found some of them but couldn't find all theese.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can turn **ON/OFF**  wifi,bluetooth,reduce display brightness-volume but you can't directly to for **mobile data** and **gps**. for those things you need to Manually push an intent.
[bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android),[WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device) ,[brightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically),[Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670524/how-to-turn-the-volume-to-max-programmatically-on-android), [GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android) ,[mobile-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically)