# How to act VOLUME_UP action by code instead of pressing on phone

Tags: android, android-activity, keyevent

Is it possible to implement a VOLUME_UP action by code/programming Android, instead of user interaction in the phone? How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to increase the volume or do you want to override the action when pressing the volume up key?

Comment: No. I just want to control it by code instead of press the physical button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15670562/1269953 instead of maximum volume specify the volume you want in the second parameter. Doc here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html