# Change volume of an alarm

Tags: android, media

I want to set volume for an alarm. I use this code but nothing seems to happen with the volume, only logs show value of volume that I'd set. What should I do to actually change volume?

My code:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));

        final AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        Log.e("Point_1", "Volume " + currentVolume);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,0,0);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                Log.e("Point_1", "Volume_after " + audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
            }

    }, 5000);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
    (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                             [int value],
                             [if desired a flag]);
```

you should use `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` instead of `AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM`

and see [How to correctly set MediaPlayer audio stream type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536391/how-to-correctly-set-mediaplayer-audio-stream-type) too

Comment: Hey,Thanks! Also, can you please tell me is there any way to get the max volume divide it by into 100 and then use it as a value for setStreamVolume?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670524/how-to-turn-the-volume-to-max-programmatically-on-android

Comment: Is there a way I can play stream even while in call and on loud speaker at max ?